# Extjs4.1.1GA GridPanel scrollbar not showing up

Tags: extjs4.1

Here is simple code from application I am working on:

```
           {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activeTab: 0,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    title: 'Proposed Benchmarkss',
                    store: 'BenchmarkLookupStore',
                    plugins: [cellEditing],
                    scroll: true,
                    columns: [
                        new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
                        {
                            dataIndex: 'code',
                            text: 'Code',
                            flex: 1
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Additional Comments',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'htmleditor'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

I am using Extjs4.1.1 GA, Number of records are 300 but I don't see the scrollbar on grid panel. I put scroll: true and still I don't see scrollbar.
Only way I am getting scrollbar is by putting height:200 on gridpanel.

Very strange !

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely confusing the layout engine by putting multiple items in the tab panel with a  fit layout.  It's designed to stretch a single item to take up the entire body of it's parent element.  I would change to using a vbox layout on the tab panel instead of a fit layout and give the grid panel and the additional comments panel either flex or height properties (likely a set height in pixels on comments and flex: 1 on the grid panel).  Also, if there any containers up from the tab panel that aren't shown here, make sure that they have a layout set and are being applied correctly.